# How do I update an AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm using ***CloudFormation*** yaml templates to build an infrastructure in AWS. I have an ***AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup*** that uses a LaunchTemplate (***AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate***).

I made a change to the UserData in the LaunchTemplate and pushed the changes.

Everything built ok, but on closer inspection, the UserData changes had not been applied and the AutoScalingGroup had not updated - it was still the same version that had been running for months.

If I understand the documentation correctly, in order for this to work, I need to create a ***LaunchTemplateVersion*** based on the existing LaunchTemplate and including the amendments.
However, in CloudFormation there doesn't appear to be a AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplateVersion. The only reference I can find to do this is via the aws cli using aws ec2 create-launch-template-version.

To try to work around the problem, I amended the name of my LaunchTemplate and updated the AutoScalingGroup to reference it.
This initially appeared to do the trick, I was able to login to the linux server running in the AutoScalingGroup and confirm the UserData had been applied. However, CloudFormation had a problem and decided to roll the whole deployment back.

My question(s) are:-

Is what I am trying to do sensible and if so, how do I achieve this using CloudFormation?

If it's not sensible, does anyone have any alternative suggestions?

If I have really misunderstood how this works, are there any well written resources that explain setup rather than just listing the individual command that are available?

Many thanks

mark

```
ec2AutoScalingGroup:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  DependsOn: assocEnclaveCert
  CreationPolicy:
    AutoScalingCreationPolicy:
      MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent: 100
    ResourceSignal:
      Timeout: PT15M
      Count: 1
  UpdatePolicy:
    AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
      WillReplace: true
  Properties:
    MinSize: !Ref autoScalingMinSize
    MaxSize: !Ref autoScalingMaxSize
    DesiredCapacity: !Ref autoScalingMinSize
    TargetGroupARNs:
      - !Ref nlbTargetGroup
    VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref privateSubnetIDs
    LaunchTemplate: 
      LaunchTemplateId: !Ref ec2LaunchTemplate
      Version: !GetAtt ec2LaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
    Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Ref environmentType
        PropagateAtLaunch: true



ec2LaunchTemplate:
  Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
  Properties:
    LaunchTemplateData:
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Arn: !GetAtt iamInstanceProfile.Arn
      ImageId: !FindInMap
        - region2AMI
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - AMI
      InstanceType: !Ref ec2InstanceType
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref ec2SecurityGroup
      EnclaveOptions:
        Enabled: true
      UserData: !Base64 
        'Fn::Join':
          - ''
          - - |
              #!/bin/bash -xe
            - |
            - '/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v '
            - '-c install'
            - '         --stack '
            - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
            - '         --resource ec2LaunchTemplate '
            - '         --region '
            - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
            - |+

            - '/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? '
            - '         --stack '
            - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
            - '         --resource ec2AutoScalingGroup '
            - '         --region '
            - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
            - |+

  Metadata:
    Comment: Install a simple application
    'AWS::CloudFormation::Init':
      configSets:
        !If
          - useSsmAgent
          - install:
            - install_and_enable_cfn_hup
            - config1
            - config2
            - config3
            - SSM
          - install: 
            - install_and_enable_cfn_hup
            - config1
            - config2
            - config3
      install_and_enable_cfn_hup:
        files:
          /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf:
            content: !Sub |
              [main]
              stack=${AWS::StackId}
              region=${AWS::Region}
              verbose=true
              interval=5
            mode: "000400"
            owner: root
            group: root
          /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
            content: !Sub |
              [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
              triggers=post.update
              path=Resources.EC2.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
              action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ec2LaunchTemplate --configsets install --region ${AWS::Region}
            mode: "000400"
            owner: root
            group: root
          /lib/systemd/system/cfn-hup.service:
            content: |
              [Unit]
              Description=cfn-hup daemon
              
              [Service]
              Type=simple
              ExecStart=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup
              Restart=always
              
              [Install]
              WantedBy=multi-user.target
            mode: "000400"
            owner: root
            group: root
        commands:
          01enable_cfn_hup:
            command: systemctl enable cfn-hup.service
          02start_cfn_hup:
            command: systemctl start cfn-hup.service
      config1:
        files:
          /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html:
            content: !Sub  
              - >-
                <img src="${Example}/cloudformation_graphic.png"
                alt="AWS CloudFormation Logo"/>
                
                <h1>Welcome, this is a Nitro Enclave server test</h1>
                
                <h1>You are viewing this page over a secure connection thanks
                to the ACM for Nitro Enclaves Integration</h1>

                <h2>Instance: INSTANCEID</h2>
                <h2>Region: ${AWS::Region}</h2>
              - Example: !FindInMap 
                  - region2Examples
                  - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                  - Examples
            mode: '000644'
            owner: root
            group: root

          /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
            content: !Sub |
              user nginx;
              worker_processes auto;
              error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
              pid /run/nginx.pid;
              ssl_engine pkcs11;

              # Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
              include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

              events {
                  worker_connections 1024;
              }

              http {
                  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

                  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

                  sendfile            on;
                  tcp_nopush          on;
                  tcp_nodelay         on;
                  keepalive_timeout   65;
                  types_hash_max_size 4096;

                  include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                  default_type        application/octet-stream;

                  # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
                  # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
                  # for more information.
                  
                  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

                  server {
                      listen       80;
                      listen       [::]:80;
                      server_name  _;
                      root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

                      # Load configuration files for the default server block.
                      include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

                      error_page 404 /404.html;
                          location = /40x.html {
                      }

                      error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                          location = /50x.html {
                      }
                  }
              }
            mode: '000644'
            owner: root
            group: root
          /etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf:
            content: !Join 
              - ''
              - - |
                  [main]
                - stack=
                - !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
                - |+

                - region=
                - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                - |+

            mode: '000400'
            owner: root
            group: root
      config2:
        commands: 
          mv:
            command: "mv /etc/nitro_enclaves/acm.example.yaml /etc/nitro_enclaves/acm.yaml"
      config3:
        commands:
          NitroEnclavesACMStart: 
            command: "systemctl start nitro-enclaves-acm.service"
          NitroEnclavesASMEnable:
            command: "systemctl enable nitro-enclaves-acm"
      SSM:
        commands:
          SSMEnable:
            command: "systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent"
          SSMStart:
            command: "sudo systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Launch Template version number is returned by [AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-launchtemplate.html#aws-resource-ec2-launchtemplate-return-values) and is called `LatestVersionNumber`. Then you use that return value in [AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup LaunchTemplateSpecification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-autoscaling-autoscalinggroup-launchtemplatespecification.html#cfn-autoscaling-autoscalinggroup-launchtemplatespecification-version).

Comment: Thanks for you reply Marcin. Yes, I am already referencing LatestVersionNumber. My issue is that I do not seem to be able to actually create a new version of the  AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate.

Comment: @mark You have to update your question with concrete, reproducible example of CFN template. Otherwise, its difficult to speculate what is your template and why it does not work.

Comment: Apologies @Marcin, I've added the AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup and AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate beneath my initial question above.
So the issue I have is that this code deploys with no problems, but if for example I then change the port from 80 to 8080 or change the text of the html document that is served, then these changes do not appear.  I think I need to create a new version of the template, but simply changing the code above does not appear to affect any changes. clearly I am missing some understanding of how this works.